# Execute child components function when the child is hidden

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a child component which is current not visible on the page. It is manipulated using a boolean value.

I want to execute its function even if it is not being displayed.
I have declared the child components instance like below:

```
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
```

But when I execute its function, the **child** variable is shown as undefined, since it is hidden(that's what I think).

Comment: Is it hidden, or deleted from the DOM ? is it `*ngIf` or `display: hidden` ?

Comment: So if you have used `*ngIf` for the child or trying to load it dynamically, you will not be able to get it until it's loaded in DOM. However if you are just using hide/show for the child, you should be able to grab it using @ViewChild

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ***ngIf** to hide your ChildComponent, it will not read your @ViewChild(ChildComponent) since *ngIf means you're omitting something on your DOM that will not be physically visible.*

Whereas if you use **[hidden]** on your ChildComponent, *it will be hidden on your DOM but still exists on your template* and your @ViewChild(ChildComponent) will be able to read it.

```
<child [hidden]="true"></child>    // Try using [hidden] rather than *ngIf
```